# JavaScript Repeating song in a playlist coding test

Tags: javascript

I was trying to step up my game by doing some tests that aren't basic level (this one might be basic). This is the test:

```
A playlist is considered a repeating playlist if any of the songs contain a reference to a previous song in the playlist. Otherwise, the playlist will end with the last song which points to null.
Implement a function isRepeatingPlaylist that, returns true if a playlist is repeating or false if it is not.
For example, the following code prints "true" as both songs point to each other:


  let first = new Song("Hello");
  let second = new Song("Eye of the tiger");
  
  first.nextSong = second;
  second.nextSong = first;
  
  console.log(first.isRepeatingPlaylist());
```

This is what I have so far:

```
class Song {
    name;
    nextSong;
    
    constructor(name) {
      this.name = name;
    }
  
    /**
     * @return {boolean} true if the playlist is repeating, false if not.
     */
    isRepeatingPlaylist() {
      // Your code goes here
      let songsInPlaylist= new Set();
      let current = this.name;
      while(current){
        if(current.name in songsInPlaylist){
          return true;
        } 
        songsInPlaylist.add(current.name)
        current= this.nextSong
      }
      return false;
    }
  }
  
  let first = new Song("Hello");
  let second = new Song("Eye of the tiger");
  
  first.nextSong = second;
  second.nextSong = first;
  
  console.log(first.isRepeatingPlaylist());
```

I think I could approach it by using a `let taken= Set()` and save the songs that are already played and compare it with the new ones, but I just could not move forward.

Update: I tried to include a while loop but I am failing to understand how to access the next song using this. I tried to add the current song to a set and then looping through it to compare it with the next one.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: You need a loop that keeps moving to the next song. If it's the same as `this` you've looped around and can return true. If it's null (end of list reached), return false.

Comment: Hello @ChrisG, I tried to loop through it with a while loop but it seems to be an endless loop. I tried to save it in a set but still can wrap my head around how to access the next song with `this`. I edited the question with my most recent code. Any advise?

Comment: Two small issues: 1. `let current = this.name;` needs to be `let current = this;` 2. `if(current.name in songsInPlaylist){` needs to be `if (songsInPlaylist.has(current.name)) {`

Comment: Note that you don't need a Set in the first place. You can do `while (current && current.nextSong)` then exit if `current === this` (this still refers to the first song). If the playlist loops, no song has an empty .nextSong so given that the number of songs is finite, you must hit the first one again.